# Unit testing System.IO.FileStream

Tags: unit-testing, filestream

Does anyone know how can I write a unit test for function that contains FileStream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to have more context around what you're actually trying to test.  Are you trying to parse the stream/write to the stream/something else?

Your best bet here would be to have that function use a Stream instead of a FileStream.  That way, in your test, you could use an in-memory stream and give it the data you want instead of having to create a test file on the file system.  This is beneficial because your test would run faster, woudn't be dependent on machine state, and wouldn't need to have Setup/Teardown code that's touching the system.

In general, there should be very few components in your system that should be talking directly to the file system/database/etc.  Really what you're after is either a Stream or higher-level object that just happens to be persisted in a file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's no longer unit test but integration test as you are depending on an external system => the file system. So you could pass as parameter to the method the path to the file and then recreate some sample file for the test project and then assert things on this file. You could work with relative filenames and mark the file as Copy Always so that it is deployed for each test iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you classed used the interface IDbFileIo shown here, then you could make a mock memory stream return value instead of loading the actual file.

```
public interface IDbFileIo
{
    MemoryStream LoadFile(); 
}
```

... implementation

```
public MemoryStream LoadFile()
{
    string databasePath = _pathInfo.GetFullDatabasePath();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(databasePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```